# How to calculate negative numbers in JS date sys?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a game project, where this takes place in a medieval fantasy world, and the timing system is based on JS's Data system. In this case, the game takes place in the year 1317, and I use the milliseconds for all calculations of effects, potions and things like that. However, this value is returning some logical problems in my system. The initial value in milliseconds is -19964319812000, a negative number.
Here is an example of a problem, the function of converting milliseconds to minutes and hours.

```
const msToTime = function(milliseconds) {
    let minutes = Math.round((milliseconds/ (1000 * 60)));
    let hours = Math.round((milliseconds/ (1000 * 60 * 60)));
    let days = Math.round((milliseconds/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));

    if (minutes < 60) return minutes + " Min";
    else if (hours < 24) return hours + " Hrs";
    else return days + " Days";
}
```

With positive numbers, this works normally, but dealing with negative milliseconds, this causes logical problems. Eg...

```
console.log(msToTime(2500000)); "41 Min"
console.log(msToTime(-2500000)); "-2500 Sec"
```

I would like to ask if anyone knows a solution, or how to properly handle negative dates, thank you.

Comment: Using modern Date functions makes no sense for XIV century dates, because our calendar didn't even exist back then. Since you're making just a game and not some kind of historical software, I'd suggest you simply use "2000" or similar in your calculations and then just subtract whatever you need from the year value when displaying it back to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you could use Math.abs for this.

```
const msToTime = function(milliseconds) {
    let minutes = Math.round((Math.abs(milliseconds)/ (1000 * 60)));
    let hours = Math.round((Math.abs(milliseconds)/ (1000 * 60 * 60)));
    let days = Math.round((Math.abs(milliseconds)/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));

    if (minutes < 60) return minutes + " Min";
    else if (hours < 24) return hours + " Hrs";
    else return days + " Days";
}
console.log(msToTime(2500000)); "42 Min"
console.log(msToTime(-2500000)); "42 Min"
```

Answer (score 0):

> 

```js
const msToTime = function(milliseconds) {
    let isNegative = '';
    if (milliseconds.toString().includes("-")) {
        isNegative = "-";
    }
    let minutes = Math.round(Math.abs(milliseconds/ (1000 * 60)));
    let hours = Math.round(Math.abs(milliseconds/ (1000 * 60 * 60)));
    let days = Math.round(Math.abs(milliseconds/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));

    if (minutes < 60) return isNegative + minutes + " Min";
    else if (hours < 24) return isNegative + hours + " Hrs";
    else return  isNegative + days + " Days";
}


console.log(msToTime(2500000)); // 42 Min
console.log(msToTime(-2500000)); // -42 Min
```